# Git checkout and commit

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm new to git and have a problem. I checked out my branch and then wrote some code,I did commit after I have branch which is next after checkout and I don't see my changes. How can I get back my changes?

Comment: As near as I can tell, you committed a branch and then checked out another branch, and did not see your changes. You need to `merge` or `rebase` in order to get your changes from one branch to another.

Comment: Are you using SourceTree for Windows or Mac?